# sending utf-8 adress to urlretrieve in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, urllib2

While trying to access a file whose name contain utf-8 chars from browser I get the error

```
The requested URL /images/0/04/×¤×ª×¨×•× ×•×ª_×ª×¨×’×™×œ×™×_×¢×œ_×ž×©×˜×—×™×_×“×™×¤'_2014.pdf was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`
```

In order to access the files I wrote the following python script:

```
# encoding: utf8
__author__ = 'Danis'
__date__ = '20/10/14'

import urllib

curr_link = u'http://math-wiki.com/images/0/04/2014_\'דיפ_משטחים_על_פתרונות.nn uft8pdf'

urllib.urlretrieve(link, 'home/danisf/targil4.pdf')
```

but when I run the code I get the error `URLError:<curr_link appears here> contains non-ASCII characters`

How can I fix the code to get him work? (by the way I don't have access to the server or to the webmaster) maybe the browser failed not because the bad encoding of the name for the file?

Comment: So, 404 is your expected result?

Comment: No. I want to get the file. receiving files with names like `ex20-2014.pdf` works fine through the browser. I want to get the file since I think something is corrupted with the GET in this html page.

Comment: What the original url that you can download?

Comment: 'http://math-wiki.com/images/0/04/%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A4%27_2014.pdf'

Comment: That does give me 404. (with / without trailing quote). Without knowing the exact url, how can you download it?

Comment: As you said in the question, accessing the url cause 404 error.

Comment: so I can't save the file to my computer even if I know it exists on the server but simply cannot be accessed?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

Comment: Is this the correct [link](http://math-wiki.com/images/0/04/%c3%97%c2%a4%c3%97%c2%aa%c3%97%c2%a8%c3%97%e2%80%a2%c3%97%c2%a0%c3%97%e2%80%a2%c3%97%c2%aa_%c3%97%c2%aa%c3%97%c2%a8%c3%97%e2%80%99%c3%97%e2%84%a2%c3%97%c5%93%c3%97%e2%84%a2%c3%97%c2%9d_%c3%97%c2%a2%c3%97%c5%93_%c3%97%c5%be%c3%97%c2%a9%c3%97%cb%9c%c3%97%e2%80%94%c3%97%e2%84%a2%c3%97%c2%9d_%c3%97%e2%80%9c%c3%97%e2%84%a2%c3%97%c2%a4%27_2014.pdf) ?

Comment: Yes. thanks. how did you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just pass Unicode URLs into `urllib` functions; URLs must be valid bytestrings instead. You'll need to *encode to UTF-8, then url quote* the path of your URL:

```
import urllib
import urlparse

curr_link = u'http://math-wiki.com/images/0/04/2014_\'דיפ_משטחים_על_פתרונות.nn uft8pdf'
parsed_link = urlparse.urlsplit(curr_link.encode('utf8'))
parsed_link = parsed_link._replace(path=urllib.quote(parsed_link.path))
encoded_link = parsed_link.geturl()

urllib.urlretrieve(encoded_link, 'home/danisf/targil4.pdf')
```

The *specific* URL you provided in your question produces a 404 error however.

Demo:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> import urlparse
>>> curr_link = u'http://math-wiki.com/images/0/04/2014_\'דיפ_משטחים_על_פתרונות.nn uft8pdf'
>>> parsed_link = urlparse.urlsplit(curr_link.encode('utf8'))
>>> parsed_link = parsed_link._replace(path=urllib.quote(parsed_link.path))
>>> print parsed_link.geturl()
http://math-wiki.com/images/0/04/2014_%27%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A4_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA.nn%20uft8pdf
```

Your **browser** usually decodes UTF-8 bytes encoded like this, to present a readable URL, but when sending the URL to the server to retrieve, it is encoded in the exact same manner.

Comment: where the file will be saved?

Comment: if the url redirects to 404, it means that the file doesn't exist?

Comment: @DanisFischer: it means the file doesn't exist. What page was this linked from?