# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf8' in position 66: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, urllib

I have a excel-sheet with a bunch of unique url's which will trigger a download of a file.
I've automated the process using Python and pandas, but I'm struggling with finding a solution for when either:

1.the url path contains special characters
2. the filename contains special characters

```
df = pd.read_excel('MC-Redo.xlsx')
df_column = df.iloc[:,1]

def getVideo():
    for value in df_column:
        if "https://pinnacle.blob.core.windows.net/" in str(value) and " " not in str(value):
            
            if value.find('/'):
                fileName = value.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
                if not os.path.exists(path+fileName):
                    urllib.request.urlretrieve(value, fileName)

        if "https://pinnacle.blob.core.windows.net/" in str(value) and " " in str(value):
            newUrl = value.replace(' ', '%20')
            if newUrl.find('/'):
                fileName = newUrl.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
                if not os.path.exists(path+fileName):
                    try: 
                        urllib.request.urlretrieve(newUrl, fileName)
                    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
                        if e.code != 200:
                            continue
```

I'm getting following error on some of the rows Im trying to iterate over and get the video by the url

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\aleb\Python EP download\getShortURLS.py", line 63, in <module>
    getVideo()
  File "c:\Users\aleb\Python EP download\getShortURLS.py", line 55, in getVideo
    data = urllib.request.urlretrieve(newUrl, str(fileName))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 239, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1389, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1296, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1134, in putrequest
    self._output(self._encode_request(request))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1214, in _encode_request
    return request.encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf8' in position 66: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried using (with no luck):

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(newUrl, fileName.encode('utf8'))
```

The special characters that may appear in both the URL and/or filename is 'æ', 'ø' and 'å'

If I'm doing a print before the

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(newUrl, fileName)
```

I'm seeing filename:

```
"01-Første_innlogging.mp4"
```

and URL: `https://pinnacle.blob.core.windows.net/client-files/{key}/{key}/01-Første%20innlogging.mp4`

Comment: which line had the error? How about posting the full traceback message.

Comment: @tdelaney I've edited the post with the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

df = pd.read_excel('MC-Redo.xlsx')
df_column = df.iloc[:,1]

def getVideo():
    for value in df_column:
        if "https://pinnacle.blob.core.windows.net/" in str(value) and value.find('/'):
            fileName = value.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
            if not os.path.exists(path+fileName):
                curr_link = value
                parsed_link = urllib.parse.urlsplit(curr_link)
                parsed_link = parsed_link._replace(path=urllib.parse.quote(parsed_link.path))
                encoded_link = parsed_link.geturl()

                urllib.request.urlretrieve(encoded_link, fileName)
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466426/sending-utf-8-adress-to-urlretrieve-in-python) answer.

The reason is urlretrieve needs an ascii link, so you need to encode the `ø` as well. Encoded the link looks like:

```
https://pinnacle.blob.core.windows.net/client-files/%7Bkey%7D/%7Bkey%7D/01-F%C3%B8rste%20innlogging.mp4
```

Maybe you have to also encode the filename, not sure, can't test because I don't have the actual link.

Comment: Thank you so much. This seems to have done the trick. Some URL's I get 404 and the url gets scuffed, but the majority works fine :)